# MySQL: Why can't I "column_name not in (null, 'foo')"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was writing a simple MySQL query along these lines today:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL and column_name !='foo';
```

This returned the expected number of results. But I didn't love the syntax, and tried to make it more elegant:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name NOT IN (NULL, 'foo');
```

Of course, that returned 0 results.

My question is this: **Can you explain why a null value would not be in `(NULL, 'bar')`?** I think it's because you can't compare `NULL` with `NULL`, at least philosophically. But why not?

Consider this:

```
# ruby
nil == nil
# => true


/* JavaScript */
undefined === undefined
// true
```

In those languages, and nil or undefined value is equal to any other nil or undefined value. Why not in SQL?

(Bonus points about close-to-the-metal implementation details of SQL, or philosophical differences in languages?)

Comment: I can turn your argument around since SQl was on the scene long before Ruby or Javascript (and will still be there long after they are memory). Clearly Ruby and Javascript are broken and do things incorrectly because thier developers did not clearly understand how to properly handle nulls. (In other words, stop expecting things to work the same in different languages, they don't. Just accept that's the way SQL was designed before the languages you prefer were even conceived of and there are billions (or possibly more) of lines of code dependant on that not changing.

Comment: Sorry, how is that helpful again?

Comment: It shows how ethnocentric you are being. Your way is right because it is what you are used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database structural query language SQL implements **Three Valued Logic** as a means of handling comparisons with NULL field content.

```
True
False
Unknown
```

The original intent of NULL in SQL was to represent missing data in a database, i.e. the assumption that an actual value exists, but that the value is not currently recorded in the database.

So comparison with UNKNOWN value gives indeterministic result which is evalauted to FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, direct comparisons with NULL are neither true nor false, so the `IN` clause will not work. This is a fundamental feature<sup>1</sup> of the ISO SQL standard.

See this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29) entry:

> Since Null is not a member of any data domain, it is not considered a "value", but rather a marker (or placeholder) indicating the absence of value. Because of this, comparisons with Null can never result in either True or False, but always in a third logical result, Unknown.

In this way, the concept of NULL in SQL is very different from Ruby's `nil`, or JavaScript's `undefined`. Ruby's `nil` is a 'value', so `nil == nil` is *true*. However, SQL's `NULL` is not a 'value', so `NULL = NULL` is *unknown* (but so is `NULL <> NULL`). For this reason, SQL provides a different operator for comparing `NULL`'s—`NULL IS NULL` is *true*.

<sup>1: Some may disagree that this is in fact a feature.</sup>

Comment: How? My understanding of `nil` and `undefined` is that they function similarly: that a value is nonexistent. How are nonexistent and unknown different?

Answer (score 1):

> Can you explain why a null value would not be in `(NULL, 'bar')`?

Necause SQL `NULL`s are *not* equal to other `NULL`s. That's the way the SQL `NULL`s are defined, because the language uses three-value logic (3VL) <sup>*</sup>. In essence, `NULL` means "unknown", so all comparisons to it result in the unknown result - i.e. `NULL`. For example, the result of `column_name = NULL` is `NULL`, not `false`. This is the reason behind the introduction of `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators into the SQL language.

Your first solution is correct. You could also use a less straightforward solution that converts `NULL`s to `'foo'` before comparison, but the expression that results from this conversion requires more thinking to understand:

```
WHERE IFNULL(column_name, 'foo') != 'foo'
```

<sup>*</sup> The behavior of `NULL`s in SQL, especially the difference between the way they are treated during aggregation, has been a subject of a controversy. Several suggestions were made at how to "fix" this behavior, but none of them got widespread adoption because of their complexity.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "That's the way SQL is set up"?

Answer (score 1):

IN Clause expects a value, a NULL is not a value. So You really have to put the OR with the null to get the desired result.

[MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) has a good read with this.

**--EDIT--**

To answer your comment let's compare `NULL` and a `ZERO`.

Zero is a value. It is the unique, known quantity of zero, which is used meaningfully in arithmetic/math. We can do things with zero.

Null on the other hand is a non-value, it's just a placeholder for a data value which is unknown or in other word not specified. Math can't be performed on NULL. Undefined is the other term of NULL. NULL doesn't exist so we can't do anything with it. 
Null is not zero, null is not "" (empty string). Null is just a representation of an unknown piece of data.

I hope it's now clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, NULLs are not equal to other NULLs.

**If I don't tell you my age, and you don't tell me your age, do we therefore have the same age?**

No, we can't say that's a true predicate. We simply don't have enough information to say one way or the other. It's not exactly FALSE, but it's not definitely TRUE either.

Both `column_name = NULL` and `column_name != NULL` are UNKNOWN in SQL, and conditions are satisfied only of they are actually TRUE.

`column_name IN (NULL, 'foo')` is logically the same as `(column_name = NULL) OR (column_name = 'foo')`.

Likewise, `column_name NOT IN (NULL, 'foo')` is logically the same as `NOT ((column_name = NULL) OR (column_name = 'foo'))`, or `(column_name != NULL) AND (column_name != 'foo')`.

Either way, the same rules about NULL comparisons apply.

It might be convenient if SQL were to automatically convert that to `(column_name IS NULL) OR (column_name = 'foo')` but that's not the way the language is standardly defined, for better or for worse.