# SQL query returns nothing when looking for records that are not in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created two tables and populated them:

```
CREATE TABLE FirstTab (
          id integer, 
          name VARCHAR(10) );
     
INSERT INTO FirstTab VALUES (5,'Pawan'), (6,'Sharlee'), (7,'Krish'),
     (NULL,'Avtaar');
     
CREATE TABLE SecondTab (
         id integer  );
    
INSERT INTO SecondTab VALUES (5), (NULL);
```

I am trying to find the records from FirstTab that are not in SecondTab (I guess like a custom outer join?)

But this query returns nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM FirstTab AS ft WHERE ft.id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM SecondTab );
```

What is wrong with it? I should get 2 records, not 0.

I'm using Postgres on PgAdmin 4

Comment: There's an explanation of why this is happening here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019713/mysql-why-cant-i-column-name-not-in-null-foo/

Comment: But besides that, your table is problematic because you seem to have a nullable `id` column. I think this is going to lead to even more problems for you.

Comment: Don't tag spam, this question was about Postgres not MySQL. I got rid of the `mysql` tag.

Comment: `NULL` isn't an identifier. It's the absence of an identifier (read the link from BillKarwin carefully). Don't use `NULL` to try and identify ***anything***.

Comment: I created some examples, hopefully they add to the understanding of the NULL values, see https://dbfiddle.uk/qqhTNrKP

Comment: @luuk The last query may be misunderstood. As far as I understand the OP would want the `NULL` row in the results if the `NULL` row is in `ft` but not `st`. The final query may be perceived to do that, but it won't.

Comment: @MatBailie: That's why (and because I was too lazy to do so) I did not put any comments with the different queries. 

Answer (score 0):

As well as the comments from @BillKarwin, which explain the behaviour and the fundamental issues with your data, there are alternative ways to express your logic that will work as you desire.

For example;

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  FirstTab   F
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      SecondTab   S
    WHERE
          S.id           = F.id
      OR (S.id IS NULL AND F.id IS NULL)
  )
```

That said, pretending NULL equals NULL is a ***bad*** idea. NULLs don't equal each other for a reason; NULL isn't a value, it's the absence of a value.

Your query is returning the correct results. Your desire to have your query return two rows is mistaken.

Also, forcing it (such as this answer) introduces an OR condition which has a significant performance hit, dramatically undermining the ability to use indexes effectively.

Don't do it. Just use id 0 or -1 or something. Then you can ensure the value is unique, gain real equality, have shorter cleaner code, and more effectively utilise indexes.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/x1YJ3kug

Answer (score -1):

## First Way

SELECT * FROM FirstTab AS ft WHERE ft.id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM SecondTab where id is not null );

OR

## Second Way (Recommended)

select FirstTab.* from FirstTab
inner join SecondTab on FirstTab.id <> SecondTab.id

Comment: Neither of these actually works. The first won't account for NULL being in FirstTab but missing from SecondTab. The second never works correctly. Please try it in dbfiddle or similar.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).